# function pgr_pointsaspolygon(unknown) does not exist

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, ruby

Im trying to run the query below in postgresql/postgis:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(pgr_pointsAsPolygon('SELECT id::int4, ST_X(geo)::float8 AS x, ST_Y(geo)::float8 as y FROM junction WHERE id IN ( 1050062040,.. ) UNION ALL SELECT 0::int4, 80.9475631713867::float8 as x, 26.8484115600586::float8 AS y  ')) ;
```

But getting following error:

```
ERROR:  function pgr_pointsaspolygon(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ST_AsText(pgr_pointsAsPolygon('SELECT id::int4, ST_X(...
                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Have installed postgis and have pgrouting extension also.
Any help ?

Comment: which version of pgrouting are you using?

Comment: what do you get if you do `\df pgr_pointsAsPolygon`

Comment: As said, check your postgres and pg-routing version, and maybe try to cast the text with ::text ? (you may also have a quote somewhere in your original query?)

Comment: @JGH thanks for response.. pgrouting version is 3.0.0-beta and if I do \df pgr_pointsAsPolygon getting nothing...its blank

Comment: @robinloche postgres version is 11.6

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem - after installing the extension, I did not find this function. PgRouting version is 3.0.

```
> postgres=# SELECT pgr_version();  pgr_version 
> -------------
>  3.0.0-beta (1 row)
```

It can be seen that there really is no function.

```
postgres=# \df pgr_pointsAsPolygon
                       List of functions
 Schema | Name | Result data type | Argument data types | Type 
--------+------+------------------+---------------------+------
(0 rows)
```

It says [here](https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.0/en/release_notes.html#changelog-3-0-0) that this function is moved to legacy. And [here](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/550#issuecomment-513323581) about this function...

Maybe you should try installing a different version of the extension?

Answer (score 2):

As Dmitry Abt said, it seems that in pg_routing 3.0 it's no longer a function. Not sure what you're trying to do, and I never used this function, but maybe [ST_ConcaveHull](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html) (or eventually ST_ConvexHull) could do the same job? Or you still have [pgr_alphaShape](http://docs.pgrouting.org/3.0/en/pgr_alphaShape.html#pgr-alphashape) in 3.0, wich seems to be the core function for alpha shapes.

Edit: as JGH said, the signature of the pgr_alphaShape changed, so I edited the link

Comment: The [AlphaShape](http://docs.pgrouting.org/3.0/en/pgr_alphaShape.html#pgr-alphashape) signature has changed for v3. It is the function replacing  pgr_pointsaspolygon